# Simple Color Environment for htlatex

Tags: color, environments, tex4ht, htlatex

I have a class I originally used for PDF output, but now want to also have an option for HTML. I have a very basic environment where the block of text is a different color. For example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\newenvironment{specialtext}
{\begin{color}{blue}}
{\end{color}}

\begin{document}
This is normal text.
\begin{specialtext}
This is a first paragraph of special text.

This is a second paragraph of special text.
\end{specialtext}
```

It works fine for pdflatex, but if I process with htlatex, there is no color. I have spent hours searching forums, and have found that `\color` and `\begin{color}` do not work with htlatex (for reasons that are over my head). Unfortunately, `\textcolor{blue}{TEXT}` is not an option, because the input spans multiple lines.

My knowledge of htlatex and CSS are pretty limited. I tried just defining the environment in my .cfg file, and that didn't work. I also tried making a .4ht file with the same name as the class that has the environment definition (I just cribbed this from a forum; don't actually know what I'm doing):

```
\ConfigureEnv{specialtext}{\NoFonts}{\EndNoFonts}{}{}
\Css{.specialtext{font-color: blue;}}

\endinput
```

And this line then showed up in my .css file:

```
./specialtext{font-color: blue;}
```

But the paragraphs that are supposed to be "specialtext" aren't tagged with it.

Is there something really obvious I'm missing? This seems like it should be easy.

TIA!

UPDATE:
My tex4ht.cfg file is minimal. I just use it to set the margins so the text is more readable.

```
\Preamble{html}  
\begin{document}  
\Css{body { max-width : 600px; }}  
\Css{body { text-align : justify; }}
\Css{body { margin : auto; }}
\Css{img {max-width : 500px; height : auto;}}
\EndPreamble
```

"myclass.4ht" consists entirely of what I typed above. I created it solely to try to deal with this issue. (Like I said, I have pretty minimal knowledge, but everything except this has more or less worked out of the box).

Comment: it would be helpful if you posted your cfg file as well but I think that you need  something like`\ConfigureEnv{specialtext}{\HCode{<p class="specialtext">}}{\HCode{</p>}}{}{}
`

Comment: Thank you! I added the content of my .cfg file (such as it is) above responsive to your comment. I will add your suggestiong (I assume to the .4ht file) and see if that works.

Answer (score 2):

I moved your environment to a custom package, in order to make it possible to configure it using a `.4ht` file:

```
\ProvidesPackage{specialtext}
\RequirePackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{specialtextcolor}{rgb}{0,0,1}

\newenvironment{specialtext}
{\par\begin{color}{specialtextcolor}}
{\end{color}}

\endinput
```

I made two changes: I defined `specialtextcolor` color. We will use it in the `.4ht` file to pass information about color to the `CSS` file. The second change is explicit `\par` command. I suppose that you want it and it is necessary in order to avoid HTML tag mismatch that would be produced otherwise.

The configuration file `specialtext.4ht` may look like this:

```
\def\get:xcolorcss#1#2{%   
  \expandafter\extractcolorspec\expandafter{#1}{\tsf:color}%
  \expandafter\convertcolorspec\tsf:color{HTML}\tsf:color%
  \edef#2{\#\tsf:color}%                                                                                                                             
}
\ConfigureEnv{specialtext}{\ifvmode\IgnorePar\fi\EndP\HCode{<div class="specialtext">}}{\ifvmode\IgnorePar\fi\EndP\HCode{</div>}}{}{}
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \get:xcolorcss{specialtextcolor}{\color:specialtext}
  \Css{.specialtext{color:\color:specialtext;}}
}
```

The `\ifvmode\IgnorePar\fi\EndP` commands are necessary for correct paragraph handling. The `<div class="specialtext">` is used for styling it's contents.

The code in `\AtBeginDocument` command is more interesting:

```
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \get:xcolorcss{specialtextcolor}{\color:specialtext}
  \Css{.specialtext{color:\color:specialtext;}}
}
```

The `\get:xcolorcss` command extracts color name or specification in the `CSS` form and saves it in a command for a later use. We can use this command in the `\Css` command directly. It produces following code:

```
 .specialtext{color:#0000FF;}
```

It is necessary to use it inside `\AtBeginDocument`, because it is defined in `xcolor.4ht` file, which is loaded after `specialtext.4ht` (the .4ht files are loaded in order they were used in the document).

This is the resulting HTML:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! I tried this. Just to be sure I'm not dealing with collisions, I put the above text verbatim into `specialtext.sty` and `specialtext.4ht` in my local texmf path. Then I made a test.tex with just the three paragraphs. On my output, I get `!Undefined control sequence. \@begindocumenthook ...t\endcsname \get:xcolorcss{specialtextcolor}{\color:...}` 

Any thoughts on this?

Comment: @Sean which TeX distribution do you use? The `\get:xcolorcss` is quite recent addition to `tex4ht`, so you may need to update it

Comment: My html output looks just like yours, except the first line is 

specialtextcolor

And the two lines of specialtext are indented but not colored.

Comment: `This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.16 (TeX Live 2015/Debian) (preloaded format=latex)

restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
LaTeX2e <2016/02/01>
Babel <3.9q> and hyphenation patterns for 81 language(s) loaded.`

I'll see if updating to a newer version helps. Thanks again!

Comment: @sean texlive 2015 is really old, you should try to update. I've updated my answer with definition for `\get:xcolorcss` so it should work anyway.

Comment: I uninstalled the debian package and updated to the latest version of texlive via iso. It worked perfectly, and you rock! Thank you again!