# How to add frame and background color with listing when used with text4ht

Tags: listings, tex4ht

This issue is only for tex4ht. I want to move all my code formatting away from using a Javascript package I am now using, and to use listings instead.

As is known, listings package works as is with PDF. But many of its options do not work with tex4ht such as background color and putting frame around.

I looked at some related questions (some links below), but many are old and each one gives different approach and I am lost as what to do now.

What is the current best practice in tex4ht to at least support the background color and the frame to show up with text4ht? I assume I need special .css. Should I make .4ht? How to do all this is what I need help with.

Here is a MWE

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{listings,xcolor}
\definecolor{bg}{RGB}{255,255,226}

\lstset{
basicstyle=\small,
breaklines=true,
backgroundcolor=\color{bg},
language=,
frame = single,
frameround=tttt,
rulecolor=\color{gray}
}

\begin{document}
This is my listing

\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
\begin{lstlisting}                       
Methods for first order ODEs:
--- Trying classification methods ---
trying a quadrature
<- quadrature successful
\end{lstlisting}
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

Compiled with lualatex gives

[image]

Compiled with `make4ht  -ulm default foo.tex "mathjax,htm"` gives this web page

[image]

The following are related questions. I just do not know how to use solutions given so far to solve the above, if possible.

### References

[Simple Color Environment for htlatex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/422222/simple-color-environment-for-htlatex)

[Verbatim environment with background color (PDFLaTeX and tex4ht)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/53941/verbatim-environment-with-background-color-pdflatex-and-tex4ht)

Using TL 2021 on Linux

**Update 3/24/2022**

Using updated answer for making it work with `\lstinputlisting` works, but I get lots of extra `nbsp` at end of each line. Here is a MWE

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}

\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{listings,xcolor}
\definecolor{bg}{RGB}{255,255,226}

\lstset{
basicstyle=\ttfamily\small,
breaklines=true,
backgroundcolor=\color{bg},
language=,
frame = single,
frameround=tttt,
rulecolor=\color{gray}
}

\begin{document}    

This is my file:

\lstinputlisting{foo2.tex}
\end{document}
```

Compiled using

```
 make4ht  -ulm default -c ./my.cfg foo2.tex "mathjax,htm"
```

Where `my.cfg` is the updated .cfg in the answer. This gives the HTML

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this configuration file:

```
\Preamble{xhtml}
\makeatletter
\lst@AddToHook{Init}{%
\bgroup%
  % handle backround color and border in listings
  \ifx\lst@fillcolor\@empty\else%
    \lst@fillcolor%
    \extractcolorspec{.}\html@fillcolor%
    \expandafter\convertcolorspec\html@fillcolor{HTML}\html@fillcolor%
    \Css{\#listing-\listingN{background-color:\#\html@fillcolor;}}%
  \fi%
  \ifx\lst@rulecolor\@empty\else%
    \lst@rulecolor%
    \extractcolorspec{.}\html@rulecolor%
    \expandafter\convertcolorspec\html@rulecolor{HTML}\html@rulecolor%
    \Css{\#listing-\listingN{border: 1px solid \#\html@rulecolor;}}%
  \fi%
\egroup%
}
\Configure{lstinputlisting}
   {\ifvmode \IgnorePar\fi \EndP
    \HCode{<!--l. \the\inputlineno-->}%
    \gHAdvance\listingN by 1%
    \HCode{<pre class="lstinputlisting" id="listing-\listingN">}%
    \bgroup\ttfamily%\special{t4ht@(}%
       \Configure{listings}%
         {{\everypar{}\leavevmode}}%
         {{\everypar{}\leavevmode}}%
         {\HCode{\Hnewline<span class="label">}}%
         {\HCode{</span>}}%
   }
   {%\special{t4ht@)}
    \egroup%
    \ifvmode \IgnorePar\fi \EndP  \HCode{</pre>}\par}%
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\EndPreamble
```

It uses a hook that Listings executes at beginning of each environment, and extracts colors of current background and border, if they are set. It then uses CSS to assign these colors to the current listings environment.

This is the result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks Michal. Nice job. Fyi, I added `padding-left:3.0pt;`  to your `\Css{\#listing-\listingN{padding-left:3.0pt; border: 1px solid \#\html@rulecolor;}}%` line as I noticed the text was too close to the left edge border in Brave browser. This is great. I can now get rid of all the javascript library I was using as it was slowing down loading all the pages.

Comment: Hello Michal. What changes is needed to make your code work with `\lstinputlisting{file_name}` instead of just `\begin{lstlisting} code \end{lstlisting}`? Currently using `\lstinputlisting{file_name}` the code comes out without the background coloring and the Frame. I hope it is not too much change. I could not figure what I need to do. does it need separate hook? If you like me to make separate question on this please let me know. Thanks.

Comment: @Nasser  try the updated answer

Comment: Thanks Michal. It works OK, except for all those `nbsp` at end of lines. I wonder why they show up? I compile the files on Linux, but these files can reside on windows disk (I use Linux subsystem on windows). I wonder if I need to run `dos2unix` each time? I see your new code adds `nbsp` there? What is the correct way to handle this? Please see updated MWE showing the output.

Comment: Fyi, I removed `\:nbsp` from your code and this seems to have resolved the issue so far for this example. But I do not know yet what side-effect will somewhere else. I am sure you added this for some good reason.

Comment: @Nasser no, \:nbsp and even `<br />` in fact aren't necessary. try the updated file

Comment: FYI, I found small issue with using your solution with tex4ht, but in slightly different way than in this question and can't see how to fix it. To reduce clutter, I will make new question so it is clear soon and give MWE.  Your solution here works great, but it does not work when I changed to using listing styles instead. May be it just needs new hook into that package. I do not know. Thanks.

Comment: fyi, I think I will try to just use `\ifdefined\HCode` for this and use current solution for tex4ht and use the style for PDF. I think this should work. btw, any change of making the whole listing package work with tex4ht in the future? I know this is a major project. Just asking if there are any plans for this. Thanks.

Comment: @Nasser I usually add package features on user requests, with some code to test. I normally don't use Listings at all, so it is unlikely that I would add features that I don't know about.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I think after trying `\ifdefined\HCode` is making code hard to read and messy. May be I will post a question about using your solution with listing styles now after all. If you have an idea how to make it work that will be great, otherwise, will just use `\Ifdefined\HCode`